# How to Handle the Windows Authentication in Linux Machine?

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, popupwindow

1.I launch my Application
2. It will ask for my Azure email ID for Authentioncation, Once its provided .
3. Then it will ask for Windows "username" and "password" for Authentication
4.In Linux how to Handle this windows Authentication ???

Help me out on how to handle this .I tried the below code .

But its Not working .

```
Robot rb = new Robot();
  //Enter user name by ctrl-v
 StringSelection username = new StringSelection("XXXXx");      Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);            
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);      
 //tab to password entry field
 rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
 Thread.sleep(2000);
  //Enter password by ctrl-v
 StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection("YYYY");
 Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);
     rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
      rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
     //press enter
     rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: **Windows Authentication** on **Linux Machine**?

Comment: What kind of application is it?

Comment: React Js , trying to run in Linux machine. When i run in Windows machine i did not face any issues but in mac and linux its asks for Windows Authentication..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can overcome this by using the following:

```
baseUrl=”http://” + username + “:” + password + “@” + url;

driver.get(baseUrl + “/”);
```

This should bypass the window as you are authenticating upon opening the application.

Comment: First i need to launch the URL , then i need to input the Azure email Id , click Next button , then it will popup a window to enter the User Name and Password..